# Vertical-align not working as expected

Tags: css

As I was trying to get more familiar with `vertical-align` property I came across a problem. The default value of the property is `baseline`, which aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. I made the `h2` element at the bottom of the code display as `inline-block` to see how it behaves and that's when I got surprised. Shouldn't it show just right above the border of the body same as the blue box shows, instead of being somewhere in the centre of the body? It looks like aligning those boxes(divs) vertically affects where the baseline of the `body` is, but why? Please, click "Full page" when running the code snippet to see the behaviour.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vertical align</title>
 <style>
  body {border: 1px solid black; line-height: 1;}
  .box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .tall {
   height: 300px;
   background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .short {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: green;
  }
  .middle {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: yellow;
  }

  .square {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: red;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
  h2 {display: inline-block;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Vertical Align</h1>
 <div class="box tall"></div>
 <div class="box short"></div>
 <div class="box middle"></div>

 <h2>Picture aligned <div class="square"></div> within text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected `h2` to go down as you can see in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: Hey, do you mean the `h2` has to be under all 3 colored boxes and not inline?

Comment: If yes, it is because of the `display:inline-block` attribute on the `H2` itself. This aligns the div/element in the same row as long there exists horizontal space

Comment: No, I meant it should appear just above the body border just right as the blue box appears. The `vertical-align` of the `h2` is `baseline`, I just checked it in the dev tools. I edited the post and added a picture that shows what I mean. Sorry, if my description isn't understandable, English is not my first language.

Comment: `baseline` will only align to base of other textual elements present in parent elements. To achieve what you need, you can use `vertical-align:bottom;`

Comment: I see, and if I had a few more elements before `h2` whose `vertical-align` would be set to various values, then the `h2` at the bottom of the code would be aligned to the baseline of which element?

Comment: The internal [CSS priorities](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css) are as follows ID >> Class >> element (where ID is prioritized)

Comment: The parent tag ID or Class would affect the child, not the sequence of tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend reading this [vertical-align](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/) article to gain in-depth understanding of the property.

Answer (score 2):

The element is aligned this way because `baseline` aligns it with the baseline of the *text* inside the parent element.
In your case, the text baseline is pushed down by the large `inline-block` divs. The h2 aligns with this text. If you want it to align with the bottom of the other inline-elements (as shown in your image), add the style `vertical-align: bottom` to your h2.

This article explains the different vertical-align values very well:
https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Comment: To approach to the problem of OP, he must write `h2 {display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;}`. That's the correct answer (maybe you can edit and put the code example).

Comment: Keep in mind, h2 elements have some default margins. If you want text to be right at the bottom, don't forget to remove them `margin: 0;`

Comment: I added a `span` tag with some text inside before the `h2` and aligned it vertically to the top. If I leave the `vertical-align` on the `h2` the same(baseline), then the `h2` remains in the same location(aligned in the middle). Now, even though I have more elements with different `vertical-align` values before the `h2`, the `h2` still remains in the same location. Does it mean that an element whose value of `vertical-align` is `baseline` is going to be aligned the same as the first element within the parent element?

Answer (score -1):

When you are using inline-block, it is better to handle your elements by positioning them.See my changes in css-style for h2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vertical align</title>
 <style>
  body {border: 1px solid black; line-height: 1;}
  .box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .tall {
   height: 300px;
   background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .short {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: green;
  }
  .middle {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: yellow;
  }

  .square {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: red;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }
  h2 {
                  display: inline-block;
                  width:300px;
                  size:10px;
                  vertical-align:bottom;
                 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Vertical Align</h1>
 <div class="box tall"></div>
 <div class="box short"></div>
 <div class="box middle"></div>

 <h2>Picture aligned <div class="square"></div> within text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I know it can be achieved by positioning, but I would like to know how `vertical-align` works, too.

Comment: If you want this design then you should use position of h2. By applying verticle-align you will not get your mention design.-Thank you.